# Automatically change settings of Terminal when in full screen

Tags: macos, terminal, fullscreen

I often use `emacs` from a terminal (`emacs -nw`), and when comparing two files side-by-side (`C-x 3`) it is often useful to go into full-screen mode.  I'm using a 27" screen, so full-screen mode provides a lot of screen real estate, usually more than I need.  To counteract this, I typically increase the font size under `Terminal->Preferences->Setings`.

**Is there a way to have settings -- e.g. font size -- changed automatically when going to full screen in a Terminal application?**

I notice that one can define a preset `Setting`, which can be swapped out easily, but it would be nice if it was swapped out automatically when going full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try AppleScript to do something like

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set zoomed of window 0 to true
    set font size of window 0 to 24
end tell
```

but I haven't found a way to activate fullscreen mode this way yet

Comment: Great idea.  I'll need to learn a little AppleScript'ing, as I'm fairly new to Mac's :).